# JavaScript file isolated storage

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

Is there a way for a script included in an html page store some data between page openings, which would not be accessible by other scripts in that page and by other instances of that script inclusion? The script is on another domain, but it's static: there's only one link to it.

Suppose script A is included in pages B and C, all different domains.
What is necessary:

1. js from B cannot read the data saved by A
2. js from A in B cannot read the data saved by A in C

Cookies don't fit point (2) and localStorage doesn't fit (1). Is this possible to achieve?